# Get Sequence of Bytes of a file Saved in Disk in Python 3

Tags: python, binaryfiles

Any data file is written to disk  as a stream/sequence of binary bytes. How to get these sequence of binary bytes of a file exactly it is written/saved in a hard drive in Python 3?
For example,  how I can get a string of bytes of a .mp3 file that are saved in disk for the .mp3 file?

I tried,

```
with open("file_full_path", "rb") as file: #--> open file in binary read mode
    binary_data = file.read() #--> read all binary data
```

but when I give an mp3 file as input to it gives me back string like this - `b'ID3\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0fvTIT2\`, when I give a text file as input then it gives me the exact text written in file,this is not how file are saved in disk, files are saved as a sequence of 0 and 1, i want to get those binary sequences for files.

**For example, if `a.mp3` is a file of 1.5 MB, so in computer `a.mp3` is saved as a binary sequences of 1.5 MB, I want to get those  binary sequences of 1.5 MB in a string. How can I do that?**

**PS:** I am new to the topic, plz comment *related terms* that should be used in this post.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, nor is it meant to provide personalized guides and tutorials. See: [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you are looking for this,

```
with open("file_full_path", "rb") as file: #--> open file in binary read mode
    binary_data = file.read() #--> read all binary data
```

Comment: when I give an mp3 file as input to it gives me back string like this - `b'ID3\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0fvTIT2\ `, when I give a text file as input then it gives me the exact text written in file,this is not how file are saved in disk, files are saved as a sequence of 0 and 1, i want to get those binary sequences for files.

Comment: @MikeSQ that's not a string that's a bytestring, aka a bunch of bytes, each of which is 8 bits. Python helpfully *prints* ascii bytes as the corresponding letter, and non-ascii bytes as a hexadecimal escape (so `0x03` is the bits `00000011`). That's still just a representaton, what you have *is* the "binary sequence for the files". `ID3` is the "magic bytes" sequence of the id3v2 container.

Comment: Hello Sharmaji, would you kindly inform the following plz: Is exactly copying what is in hard drive? Or it is converting without going to the corresponding address and then copying from there? I need to understand how the process is working here.